# How to use IFS in bash for an array of strings?

Tags: linux, bash, ifs

Given an array of strings, I want IFS to parse each string by an underscore, join the first three separated values together using the same delimeter and output them to an empty list. For instance, if I have the array `input=("L2Control_S3_L001_R1_001.fastq", "L2Control_S3_L001_R2_001.fastq")` IFS would take the first string and separate it out by the underscore, so the output would be:

```
L2Control
S3
L001
R1
001.fastq
```

Afterward, it would take the first three separated values and join them together with an underscore: `"L2Control_S3_L001"`. Lastly, this value would be appended onto a new array `output=("L2Control_S3_L001")` this process would continue until all values in the array are completed. I have tried the below implementation, but it seems to run infinitely.

```
#!/bin/bash

str=("L2Control_S3_L001_R1_001.fastq", "L2Control_S3_L001_R1_001.fastq")

IFS='_'
final=()

for (( c = 0; c = 2; c++ )); do
  read -ra  SEPA <<< "${str[$c]}"
  final+=("${SEPA[0]}_${SEPA[1]}_${SEPA[2]}")
done
```

Can someone help me with this, please?

Comment: Your for loop is not correct. The middle condition should be something like `c < ${#str[@]}`

Comment: (1) Don't use a `,` to separate array elements -- that comma is ending up as part of your data. (2) Note that you can set IFS local to a single `read` command. `IFS=_ read -r -a arrayname` won't change `IFS` for any command other than that `read`.

Comment: BTW, I don't see a reason to use `read -a` at all when you expect exactly three pieces. `IFS=_ read -r first second third` will put the first piece in `"$first"`, the second in `"$second"`, everything after the second in `"$third"` and there you are.

Comment: And why use a counter `c` at all? `for a_str in "${str[@]}"; do` will assign each piece to `a_str` in turn.

Comment: ...but anyhow, none of the problems I see this code having have anything to do with IFS. If I'm missing something that _is_ IFS-specific, could you explain more clearly?

Comment: It's not bash, but the _most concise_ solution is awk: `printf '%s\n' "${input[@]}" | awk -F_ -vOFS=_ NF=3`. perl in awk mode comes close: `| perl -ple '@x=split "_",$_;$_=join "_",splice(@x,0,3)'`

Answer (score 1):

The `${array[*]}` expansion **joins** elements using the first character of IFS. You can combine this with the `${var:offset:length}` expansion.

```sh
output=()
for str in "${input[@]}"; do
    read -ra fields <<< "$str"
    output+=("${fields[*]:0:3}")
done
```

I find `declare -p varname ...` handy to inspect the contents of variables.

---

This can also be done with bash parameter expansion:

```sh
str="L2Control_S3_L001_R1_001.fastq"
IFS=_
suffix=${str#*"$IFS"*"$IFS"*"$IFS"}
first3=${str%"$IFS$suffix"}
declare -p str suffix first3
```

```
declare -- str="L2Control_S3_L001_R1_001.fastq"
declare -- suffix="R1_001.fastq"
declare -- first3="L2Control_S3_L001"
```

Can also do that in one line, but it's hairy:

```sh
first3="${str%"$IFS${str#*"$IFS"*"$IFS"*"$IFS"}"}"
```

Comment: I tried to do your following example using:
`input=("L2Control_S3_L001_R1_001.fastq" "L2Control_S3_L001_R2_001.fastq")`

`output=()`
`for str in "${input[@]}"; do`
  `read -ra  feilds <<< "$str"`
  `output+=("${feilds[*]:0:2}")`
`done`

`for str_a in "${output[@]}"; do`
    `echo "$str_a"`
`done`

However it just printed out the samething that was in the input: `"L2Control_S3_L001_R1_001.fastq" "L2Control_S3_L001_R2_001.fastq"`

Comment: When testing that, did you set `IFS=_`

Answer (score 1):

Setup (notice no comma needed to separate array entries):

```
str=("L2Control_S3_L001_R1_001.fastq" "L2Control_S3_L001_R1_001.fastq")
```

One idea using a `while/read` loop to parse the input strings into 4 parts based on a delimiter (`IFS=_`):

```
final=()

while IFS=_ read -r f1 f2 f3 ignore
do
    final+=("${f1}_${f2}_${f3}")
done < <(printf "%s\n" "${str[@]}")

typeset -p final
```

Where the variable `ignore` will be assigned fields #4-#n.

This generates:

```
declare -a final=([0]="L2Control_S3_L001" [1]="L2Control_S3_L001")
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a lengthy description of taking the first 3 elements separated by `_`.

```
printf "%s\n" "${str[@]}" | cut -d_ -f-3
```